# What's a word for when someone is drawing out a story for dramatic effect?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

"Quit _________ , and get to the point!"

None of these seem quite right, although any of them would suffice:

- Dawdling
- Dilly-dallying
- Delaying
- Prolonging
- Protracting

I think I'm looking for a word that's specifically concerned with relating an event in conversation. Or maybe I've forgotten a word that never existed in the first place. I do that sometimes.

Comment: Hi justnoah, welcome to EL&U and good luck with your first question! Don't forget to take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: The title of your question is at odds with the body of your question. Drawing out a story for dramatic effect is often a *good* thing—it makes it interesting and engages the listener. On the other hand, talking on at length in such as way as to make the listener annoyed is a *bad* thing. It's not clear which you mean. (Although I suspect you need to change the title of your question.) But what do you mean by *at length*? Repeating the *same* thing over and over again—or talking endlessly about *different* things? Is there really an active sense of *delay* on the part of the speaker?

Comment: (What's wrong with any or all of the words you mention in your question? Without knowing why you don't like them, we can't guess what you might be trying to think of.)

Comment: Thanks @Chappo, didn't mean to break the rules, mainly because I wasn't aware of them in the first place. Can't use that excuse again, haha. I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Well, @JasonBassford, I don't think the two are mutually exclusive. The speaker might think it's a _good_ thing while the listener might really need to pee. To clarify, the speaker is waxing prolix (e.g., "As we're about to find out, if you would continue to allow me to hold your attention, as you have been so politely thus far...) where a laconic reply might serve. The examples I provided would suffice in a pinch, but they're not... _le mot juste_. But I thought if anywhere, this would be the part of the internet that would understand. Nobody else I know does. Sorry, prevarication, I know.

Comment: How about ''embellishing''?

Comment: @Scott I don't believe that necessarily implies a delay, so not the best fit. At least, I can think of several words that are closer to the mark. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two which leap readily to mind are "[**shilly-shallying**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shilly-shally)" and the more writerly "[**burying the lede**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lede)".

In the context of newspaper and magazine authorship of days gone by, we referred to the practise of adding *too much* fluff or exposition or description *prior* to the solid content of the lede (the enticing bit of the introductory paragraph designed to get readers to *want* to read further) as "burying the lede": people use this phrasing in conversation to refer pejoratively to those who (like me) tend to obfuscate, circumloquate and hide the main point of a narrative so deep in the verbal shrubbery that the listener becomes frustrated and feels a need to exclaim, in essence: "Get ON with the story!"

Comment: I always thought that was *'burying the **lead**'*. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I was looking for a single word, but _burying the lede_ is basically it.  I don't mind verbal shrubbery as long as it's thoughtfully arranged.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, "burying the ***lead***" is and remains the correct spelling. M-W is the only reputable dictionary that has an entry for ***lede**;* Oxford, American Heritage Dictionary, Collins, Macmillan, Cambridge and Webster's New World College Dictionary do not.

Comment: Oxford Dictionary of English, Oxford University Press, 2010, 2017: **lede** - *noun* - **US** the opening sentence or paragraph of a news article, summarizing the most important aspects of the story: *the lede has been rewritten and the headline changed*. Phrases: **bury the lede** - **US** fail to emphasize the most important part of a story or account: *one should always listen carefully to the president, as he has a tendency to bury the lede.*

Comment: American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition copyright ©2018 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt: *noun* - The introductory portion of a news story, especially the first sentence. [Obsolete spelling of LEAD, *revived in modern journalism* to distinguish the word from its homograph LEAD, strip of metal separating lines of type.]

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lede

Comment: @Scott - 
Macmillan English Dictionary (US): the opening sentence or paragraph of a news article, summarizing the most important aspects of the story
The Hill reported it this way, but the writer buried the lede.
The lede paragraph pretty much says it all.
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lede

Comment: THE AMERICAN HERITAGE® DICTIONARY OF THE ENGLISH LANGUAGE, FIFTH EDITION by the Editors of the American Heritage Dictionaries. Copyright © 2016, 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company

noun

The introductory portion of a news story, especially the first sentence.
Origin of lede

Obsolete spelling of lead revived in modern journalism to distinguish the word from its homograph lead strip of metal separating lines of type.

https://www.yourdictionary.com/lede#americanheritage

Comment: @Scott - but honestly, once we had Oxford in on this, there was no need to go further to the other, derivative sources - Oxford is, and always has been, definitive.

Comment: @GerardFalla Careful, your fanboy is showing, haha.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the verb **[digress](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digress)**, which Merriam Webster describes as:

> to turn aside especially from the main subject of attention or course of argument

But the tone of your sample sentence doesn't really fit with the rather formal word, 'digress'. I can't imagine anyone saying 'Quit digressing, and get to the point!'.

You might prefer to **[ramble](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rambling)** - defined as:

> proceeding without a specific goal, purpose, or direction: such as ...
>   straying from subject to subject

That would definitely fit in with the casual tone your sentence uses: 'Quit rambling, and get to the point'.

Comment: While _rambling_ does fit the slot, I was thinking of a term that indicated intentional delay. But I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

"Quit **dallying** , and get to the point!"

to **dally**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dally)

> To dawdle, delay, or linger; to waste time

And as in:

> “Come now, no more dallying,” he said, though more gently. Ophelia